# How to remove/ (avoid) the # sign in "Solve" output

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, hashing

I am trying to find an equation of A with variable B using the Solve function.
I have the first derivative of firm A's profit with respect to location a, which is equal to zero.
I have the first derivative of firm B's profit with respect to location b, which is equal to zero.
I compare both first derivatives.

The equations in the output contain "#".

What am I doing wrong?

How should I write the input so that the output won't include "#"?

Alternatively, how could I convert the output to another output that does not include "#"?

Thanks in advance :-)

Editing,

1.Numerical approximations using N[ ] gave me the same output.

2.Please find attached the code:

```
Solve[1/144 (19223 + 2576 a - 48 a^2 + 652 b + 12 b^2 - (
     944784 (24552 + 
        a (95733 + 2 a (20775 + 2 a (1587 + 82 a - 82 b) - 3126 b) - 
           39726 b) - 84141 b))/(4 + 14 a + a^2 - 2 (7 + a)* b + 
       b^2)^4 + (
     324 (9 (84977 + 24221 b) + 
        a (89827 - 2 a (14779 + 2 a (1217 + 38 a - 38 b) - 3234 b) + 
           69314 b)))/(4 + 14 a + a^2 - 2 (7 + a) b + b^2)^2 + (
     54 (70697 + 8770 b + 12 a*(1032 - 3 a - 4 a^2 + 6 (25 + a) b)))/(
     4 + 14 a + a^2 - 2 (7 + a) b + 
      b^2) + (5832 (9 (90413 + 77020 b) + 
          2 a (-147639 - 2 a (53867 + 8294 a + 384 a^2) + 
             4 (35031 + 4 a (1147 + 48 a)) b)))/(4 + 14 a + a^2 - 
        2 (7 + a) b + b^2)^3) == 
  1/144 (-144 + 288 b + 
     1/(4 + 14 a + a^2 - 2 (7 + a) b + b^2)^3 12 (a - b) (-13 - 7 a + 
        15 b + 2*a*b - 2*b^2)*(22 + a^2 + (-32 + b) b - 
        2 a (2 + b)) (-10 + 3 a^2 + 2 a^3 - 6 a (15 + (-7 + b) b) + 
        b (78 + b (-45 + 4 b))) + (
     2 (a - b) (16 + a - b) (-10 + 3 a^2 + 2 a^3 - 
        6 a (15 + (-7 + b) b) + b (78 + b (-45 + 4 b)))^2)/(4 + 14 a +
        a^2 - 2 (7 + a) b + 
       b^2)^3 + (6 (7 + a - b) (-a + b) (22 + a^2 + (-32 + b) b - 
          2 a (2 + b)) (-10 + 3 a^2 + 2 a^3 - 6 a (15 + (-7 + b) b) + 
          b (78 + b (-45 + 4 b)))^2)/(4 + 14 a + a^2 - 2 (7 + a) b + 
        b^2)^4 + ((22 + a^2 + (-32 + b) b - 2 a (2 + b)) (-10 + 
        3 a^2 + 2 a^3 - 6 a (15 + (-7 + b) b) + 
        b (78 + b (-45 + 4 b)))^2)/(4 + 14 a + a^2 - 2 (7 + a) b + 
       b^2)^3), {a}]
```

[image: See the input and output attached]

Comment: You can see numerical approximations using N[ ] or //N

Comment: Hi, the Root object here is just stating that the solution is the root of a function, in this case it seems to be a polynomial function given the powers of #. Unless the polynomial coefficients have structure/symmetries there is no general formula for the root of a polynomial of degree higher than 4. As such, you probably will not get anything more explicit than that for generic b although some particular values of b might yield an exact result.

Comment: If you give explicit numbers to the variables such as b then maybe you can get a numerical result with `N`. Consider also checking the documentation on `Root`. Also for future questions consider posting code rather than a screenshot as it allows users here to check what works.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = 1/144 (19223 + 2576 a - 48 a^2 + 652 b + 
      12 b^2 - (944784 (24552 + 
           a (95733 + 2 a (20775 + 2 a (1587 + 82 a - 82 b) - 3126 b) - 
              39726 b) - 84141 b))/(4 + 14 a + a^2 - 2 (7 + a)*b + 
          b^2)^4 + (324 (9 (84977 + 24221 b) + 
           a (89827 - 2 a (14779 + 2 a (1217 + 38 a - 38 b) - 3234 b) + 
              69314 b)))/(4 + 14 a + a^2 - 2 (7 + a) b + 
          b^2)^2 + (54 (70697 + 8770 b + 
           12 a*(1032 - 3 a - 4 a^2 + 6 (25 + a) b)))/(4 + 14 a + a^2 - 
         2 (7 + a) b + 
         b^2) + (5832 (9 (90413 + 77020 b) + 
           2 a (-147639 - 2 a (53867 + 8294 a + 384 a^2) + 
              4 (35031 + 4 a (1147 + 48 a)) b)))/(4 + 14 a + a^2 - 
          2 (7 + a) b + b^2)^3) == 
   1/144 (-144 + 288 b + 
      1/(4 + 14 a + a^2 - 2 (7 + a) b + b^2)^3 12 (a - b) (-13 - 7 a + 15 b + 
         2*a*b - 2*b^2)*(22 + a^2 + (-32 + b) b - 2 a (2 + b)) (-10 + 3 a^2 + 
         2 a^3 - 6 a (15 + (-7 + b) b) + 
         b (78 + b (-45 + 4 b))) + (2 (a - b) (16 + a - 
           b) (-10 + 3 a^2 + 2 a^3 - 6 a (15 + (-7 + b) b) + 
            b (78 + b (-45 + 4 b)))^2)/(4 + 14 a + a^2 - 2 (7 + a) b + 
          b^2)^3 + (6 (7 + a - b) (-a + b) (22 + a^2 + (-32 + b) b - 
           2 a (2 + b)) (-10 + 3 a^2 + 2 a^3 - 6 a (15 + (-7 + b) b) + 
            b (78 + b (-45 + 4 b)))^2)/(4 + 14 a + a^2 - 2 (7 + a) b + 
          b^2)^4 + ((22 + a^2 + (-32 + b) b - 
           2 a (2 + b)) (-10 + 3 a^2 + 2 a^3 - 6 a (15 + (-7 + b) b) + 
            b (78 + b (-45 + 4 b)))^2)/(4 + 14 a + a^2 - 2 (7 + a) b + 
          b^2)^3);
```

Looking at the real roots

```
solR = Solve[eqn, a, Reals];
```

The exact solutions are [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expressions which, due to the high order of their polynomials, cannot be expressed in terms of radicals. For specific values of `b` the numeric values can be determined.

```
{b, a} /. solR /. b -> 0
```

[image]

```
% // N

(* {{0., -47.0041}, {0., -10.8541}, {0., -8.1571}, {0., 0.0500911}, 
    {0., 0.292311}, {0., 5.03745}} *)
```

A plot of the roots may give you a sense for why they cannot be expressed in simpler form.

```
ListLinePlot[
 Transpose[
  Table[{b, a} /. solR, {b, -20, 20, 1/20}]],
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {b, a}),
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: "due to the high order of their polynomials, cannot be expressed in terms of radicals" : I am not sure what high order means here. It could mean polynomial degree or the order of the symmetry group of the roots.

Comment: @userrandrand - the first argument of these Root expressions is a polynomial. When that polynomial is degree four or less, ToRadicals will convert the Root expression to an equivalent expressions with radicals.

Comment: @userrandrand - from the documentation for `Root`, "All roots of polynomials of degree not exceeding 4 are representable in radicals"

Comment: `Root[#^10 - 1 &, 3] // ToRadicals` works. I think the documentation meant that `ToRadicals` is guaranteed to work if the degree is less than 4. It can still work for some very high degree polynomials.

Comment: `Root[Evaluate[Expand@Product[# - n, {n, 42}]] &, 20]` also works